# Loki - MBPr 15 - Screen Brightness doesn't work

Tags: display, release-loki, macbook, brightness

loving the new OS. Just installed Loki today and have a problem with screen brightness. My screen is at full brightness, which is a pain at night.

I have a MacBook Pro late 2013 11,3 with dual nvidia, intel graphics

Some steps I've attempted.

SYSTEM SETTINGS > POWER > **DISPLAY BRIGHTNESS** doesn't seem to do anything.

I ran `ls /sys/class/backlight` and got a returned result of `gmux_backlight`

I also attempted adding `setpci -v -H1 -s 00:01.00 BRIDGE_CONTROL etc=0` to `etc/local.rc` based on another question & response here. But even after reboot, still no luck.

Anyone have any trouble shooting ideas?

One thing, I did not check install 3rd party drivers at setup. Is that part of the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Not work with intel graphic card
Here is lspci output lspci 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09) 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04) 00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04) 00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)

Answer (score 2):

I found that after running `setpci` I needed to reload the `apple_gmux` module, so my `/etc/rc.local` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

setpci -v -H1 -s 00:01.00 BRIDGE_CONTROL=0
modprobe -r apple_gmux
modprobe apple_gmux

exit 0
```

Comment: This worked for me on my 2015 MBPR 15", thanks!!

Comment: I'm so glad it helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me, same might help you.. give a try!

```
sudo apt install xbacklight
```

then run

```
xbacklight -set 15
```

15 is the percentage of backlight you gonna use. You can change any percentage value according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your command. This is the correct one:

```
setpci -v -H1 -s 00:01.00 BRIDGE_CONTROL=0
```

First of all execute it in any terminal app and then try to change the brightness pressing F1/F2 keys. Add this line to your rc.local only if it works.