# Cannot change brightness with Nvidia drivers installed

Tags: nvidia, brightness

I installed elementary os Loki on my MacBook Pro which has Nvidia graphics card.

With a fresh installation I can change the brightness with the brightness keys from keyboard. But if I install the Nvidia drivers then the brightness is not changing even if I change it from the power settings.

How to solve this?

**Update**

I tried the solution given in  [Loki - MBPr 15 - Screen Brightness doesn't work](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7528/loki-mbpr-15-screen-brightness-doesnt-work) it does not works for me.

I have MacBook Pro 13 Inch 2009 model.

*Note :* 
I tried updating the graphics driver to the latest one but all I got was a blank screen after reboot.

Comment: @wolf the solution is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
This is what I am doing as a workaround:

```
sudo apt install xbacklight
```

Once installed go to System Settings>Keyboard>Shortcuts>Custom>

and bind the follow commands to keys of your choice

To Decrease:

```
xbacklight -dec 10
```

To Increase:

```
xbacklight -inc 10
```